# Nesting scenarios with feature specs in Rspec Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, integration-testing

I'm using Rspec Rails with Capybara for testing and I want to use the new [feature spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) in RSpec Rails 3 as they `read more as customer tests and acceptance tests`. However, one thing I find missing from the older (Describe/It) style is **nesting**. When trying to nest `scenarios` or use `background` inside any `scenario` block, I get an `undefined method` error. Is there anyway I could achieve nesting with feature specs to get something like this (from Michael Hartl's [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/):

```
describe "Authentication" do
    subject { page }

    describe "authorization" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "for non-signed in users" do

            describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
                before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
                it "should redirect_to to the signin page" do
                    expect(page).to have_title('Sign in')
                end

            describe "after signing in" do
                before do
                    valid_signin user, no_visit: true
                end

                it "should render the desired protected page" do
                    expect(page).to have_title('Edit user')
                end
```

Or should I be thinking in a different way about integration tests ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec, `feature` corresponds to `describe` and `scenario` corresponds to `it`.  So, you can nest instances of `feature`, but you cannot nest a `scenario` within a `scenario`, just as you cannot nest an `it` within a `it`.

Answer (score 6):

Nested `feature` with `scenarios` is available in `Capybara version 2.2.1`

In Gemfile include

```
gem "capybara", "~> 2.2.1"
```

and `bundle install`

As per official documentation of Capybara

> **feature** is in fact just an alias for **describe** ..., :type => :feature,
>   **background** is an alias for **before**, **scenario** for **it**, and **given**/**given!**
>   aliases for **let**/**let!**, respectively.

Here is the [original issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1113) and later it was [accepted and merged](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/61524b0fd32a1fb55b82853bdc4a0293e9fcdef0) in version 2.2.1

Comment: I am using the right version but was doing the wrong thing. Thanks